# Is there any way to connect local database from internet browser?

Tags: c#, java, silverlight, flash, air

I need to find a way to develop a program which can run local and server side. 
I don't know silverlight/flash or something else can do it.
Is there any framework/language/platform which can work over internet when internet connection exists and can work when internet went off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are talking about an Internet app that will work in a disconnected state.

Silverlight in OOB (Out Of Browser) mode will do that.

As for the "database", you can access "Isolated storage" from Silverlight (even when in the browser), but even more freedom to access system files in OOB mode.

The issue you will have is getting your service calls to fail gracefully when the connection is not present (or detecting disconnection and not make the calls at all).

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/out-of-browser/demo/ is a demo of silverlight.